# Use CreateComObject with DLL in another directory

Tags: c#, delphi, com

I have a C# class that is COM-visible.  I have imported it into my Delphi XE project using the Import Component (Import Type Library) wizard.  If I place the C# .DLL in the same directory as my Delphi .EXE, I can use the .Create method of the imported .PAS (TLB) file to create an instance of this class and use its methods/functions.  I would like to move this .DLL to another directory.  Is it possible to use the Create method to create an instance of this class if it is in another directory?  Or is it possible to instruct the application to look for the new DLL in another directory?

I need to put the DLL in another directory, because I have to use new versions of DLLs that are currently in the same directory as the EXE and I cannot overwrite the old DLLs in the executable's directory (it is a legacy app that needs those old DLLs).  So, I plan to put all of the new DLLs in a subdirectory and call the new function.

I have already tried to put it in a subdirectory and the application cannot locate the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CreateComObject](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Win.ComObj.CreateComObject) do not take a filename as argument. It takes a `GUID` which is used to find where the COM object is located. The information comes from the registry with entries created when the COM object has been registered.

`CreateComObject` is a wrapper around Windows API function [CoCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance).

If you move the DLL, you must register it again to reflect the new place.

Comment: Or, use a Registration-Free COM manifest in your client app.  But yes, either way, COM has to be told ahead of time where to find the DLL, wherever it happens to reside.